# How to automatically update a statusbar message?

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar

I am using Qt 5.15.1 and C++ to create a simple app which processes signals from hardware and displays images and driver status. I want to update the statusbar message when an int value defined in another class changes. I would like this to happen automatically, each time this value changes. I understand that I need signals and slots to achieve this. So far I have done the following:

signalprocessing.h

```
class SignalProcessing: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SignalProcessing(QObject *parent = nullptr);
private:
    int status;
public slots:
    int GetStatus();
signals:
    void StatusChanged();
}
```

signalprocessing.cpp

```
SignalProcessing::SignalProcessing(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
{
}
int SignalProcessing::GetStatus()
{
    emit(StatusChanged());
    return status;    
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~MainWindow();
    SignalProcessing *signalProcessing;
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    signalProcessing= new SignalProcessing(this);
    ui->statusbar->showMessage(QString::number(signalProcessing->GetStatus()));
}
```

The problem is that the statusbar message is currently not updated automatically, but set to a given value.

How do I make sure it will always display the current status?

Comment: Indeed, this could be achieved using [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). You have to connect the `StatusChanged` signal to a slot which updates the status bar.

Comment: Would that mean a signal from the SignalProcessing class and a slot in the MainWindow class? I know the QStatusBar has a public slot named "showMessage" which would fit this purpose. How do I make sure though, that the value is passed by the signal though?

Comment: Connection between `SignalProcessing` and `MainWindow` is the easiest solution. Connection to `showMessage` directly is possible if the argument types match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you want to emit your `StatusChanged` signal when the value has actually changed, not when you call `GetStatus()`. So you need a SetStatus() function, and your SignalProcessing class will need to know when to call that. Then you want to connect that signal to a slot that then updates your status bar. It might look something like this:

```
class SignalProcessing: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SignalProcessing(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int getStatus();
    void setStatus(int value);
private:
    int status;
signals:
    void statusChanged();  // It's better to start signals with a lower case letter
}
```

signalprocessing.cpp

```
SignalProcessing::SignalProcessing(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
{
}
int SignalProcessing::getStatus()
{
    return status;    
}
void SignalProcessing::setStatus(int value)
{
    if (status != value)
    {
        status = value;
        emit statusChanged();
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~MainWindow();
    SignalProcessing *signalProcessing;
public slots:
    void updateStatus();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    signalProcessing= new SignalProcessing(this);
    connect(signalProcessing, &SignalProcessing::statusChanged, this, &MainWindow::updateStatus);
    updateStatus();
}

void MainWindow::updateStatus()
{
    ui->statusbar->showMessage(QString::number(signalProcessing->getStatus()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JarMan, this is what I have been doing all along and it is aligned with the example given in Qt's documentation. However, I must be doing something wrong in the SignalProcessing code, since the status is not updated, even if I forcefully fail a driver setting or deliberately set the status value to some integer (e.g. -1).

Comment: You included the call to `connect`?

Comment: Yup. The thing I can observe through debugging is that the setStatus() method is not called in the process and that is supposed to be the object which emits the statusChanged() signal. I believe it is because I haven't called the setStatus() method anywhere in the SignalProcessing class. Instead, I am only assigning a value to the status int as such (example): status = McGetParamInt(channel, MC_Elapsed_Pg, &elapsedPages);

Comment: Right, it's up to you to call setStatus whenever the value changes.

Comment: Ok! Got it :) Thank you for the solution! I see that to achieve what I need I would have to call the setStatus() method in so many places, I am thinking it might impact performance and I feel this is not an elegant solution. I might have to rethink the purpose of this statusbar in my UI.

Comment: Signals and slots are fundamental to how Qt works. Not sure what's inelegant about this.

Comment: Signals and Slots are totally fine. It is my code which for the purpose of continuous status reporting would have to call the setStatus method many times - that's what seems a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

First change singal declartion so it will provide new value:

```cpp
class SignalProcessing: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SignalProcessing(QObject *parent = nullptr);
private:
    int status;
public slots:
    int setStatus(int value);
signals:
    void statusChanged(const QString& message);
}

void SignalProcessing::setStatus(int value)
{
    if (status != value)
    {
        status = value;
        emit statusChanged(tr("Status is %1").arg(status));
    }
}
```

Then connect this signal to [QStatusBar::showMessage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html#showMessage) slot and you done.